# Why do these recurrences determine the number of ways of tiling a 3xN rectangle with 2x1 dominoes?

Tags: recurrence-relation, dynamic-programming, correctness-proof

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10918

The above link is a solution to UVa 10918 Problem. The problem is based on Dynamic Programming. I am not able to understand this approach to the problem. I have coded the solution but the approach is completely different. I want to understand the given approach. The problem is:

Determine in how many ways can a 3xN rectangle be completely tiled with 2x1 dominoes.

I only want to know how these recurrence relations came:

```
f(n)=f(n-2)+2*g(n-1)
g(n)=f(n-1)+g(n-2)
```

where f(n)=number of tilings of a 3xN rectangle
g(n)= number of tilings of a 3xN rectangle with one of its corner squares removed

Comment: It is explained on the site. So can you be more explicit as to what you do not understand?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: correctness of recurrences is typically shown by induction (here on $n$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that the rectangle to be tiled has 3 rows and $n$ columns.

```
□□□...□
□□□...□
□□□...□
123...n
```

Consider a tiling of this rectangle using 2$\times$1 dominos. There are two basic options:

1. All tiles touching the $n$th column are horizontal. There must be 3 of them, and if you remove them, you get a tiling of a rectangle of size $3\times(n-2)$.

   ```
   □□□...⧆⧆
   □□□...■■
   □□□...⧆⧆
   123....n
   ```
2. Exactly one tile touching the $n$th column is vertical. It can either touch the top or the bottom. For each of these two options, if you remove it then you get a tiling of a rectangle of size $3\times (n-1)$ with one corner square added. That square must be tiled by a horizontal tile, after whose removal you are left with a tiling of a $3\times(n-1)$ rectangle with one corner square <strike>removed</strike> added.

   ```
   □□□...⧇⧇      □□□...□⧆
   □□□...□⧆      □□□...□⧆
   □□□...□⧆      □□□...⧈⧈
   123....n      123.....n

       |             |
       V             V

   □□□...□□     □□□...□
   □□□...□      □□□...□
   □□□...□      □□□...□□
   123....n     123....n
   ```

This explains the formula $f(n) = f(n-2) + 2g(n-1)$.

The same sort of analysis yields the formula for $g(n)$, but I leave that one for you.

Answer (score 10):

The picture should say more than words.

[image: 2x1 domino's on a 3xn strip]

Comment: But if you need the words, see the answer by @Yuval-Filmus.

Comment: Sorry. As @babou observes above the first link in the question has some explanation *and* these pictures (albeit as ascii art). So how can they help?